# En mi Visual Studio no veo mi código de esa manera alguien sabe como ponerlo así para Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero tenerlo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Normalmente lo veo así, no tengo ninguna extensión extra mas que la de flutter y dart

Comment: ¿Ya agregaste las extensiones [Dart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code) y [Flutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter)?

Comment: Añade tu código en formato texto, las imágenes no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Son extensiones que se les agrega al editor, tienes que ir buscando la que mas se parezca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Visual Studio puedes buscar en el apartado de Extensiones
"Tree" y navegar por el que mas te guste.

Para que el fondo se vea de Color negro, en el mismo apartado
puedes buscar la palabra "Theme" y apareceran de igual forma
demasiadas extensiones.

Puedes elegir la que más te guste.

Espero haberte ayudado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]